# Google+ native share dialogue instantly disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm adding sharing on google+ within my app.

I've followed the tutorial on the developers platform.

The sign-in method is working. It opens the google+ app, and then after log in, it goes back to my app.

But I can't manage to make the share working as I want.

If I use

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog]
//and
[shareBuilder open];
```

it opens safari, and after sharing, returns to the last website visited on safari.

But when trying to use

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
```

instead of the normal `shareDialog`, the view appears after calling `[shareBuilder open]`, but immediately disappear after being shown. No time to see anything on it.

Ideally, I want to use the native share dialog and pre-fill the text (which by the way doesn't work with the normal share dialog), but it's ok too if I manage to open google+ app or website, and then go back to my app.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the user is correctly logged in? Which version of the Google+ SDK are you using? What scopes and actions are you requesting?

Comment: I think yes, my user is correctly logged in. When my app launch, I call `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];` and then, just before displaying the share dialogue, I test the authentication with `if([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication])`. I've dowloaded the latest Google+ SDK available on their developper website.

Comment: What about the scopes and actions ? Have you setup your Google+ API settings on the google developer console ?

Comment: Wow... `Api and authentication/API` might be the only rubric where I didn't go to do some settings. And indeed, activate Google+ API did the trick. Maybe I'm wrong, but following the steps described in the documentation, I haven't seen anywhere something about that. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also ebable the Google+ Api in the [Google developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)